# getting multiple inputs from a key pad in python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi2, keypad

I have a raspberry pi that I need to get a 2 digit number to from a 3x4 key pad using python. The key pad works fine as I can get a single number, but I have not been able to get 2.

The code that gets the single number is:

```
kp=keypad()
digit = None
while digit == None:
      digit = kp.getKey()

print digit
```

My current attempt:

```
kp=keypad()

digit = None
fin = ""
extra = ""
geb = ""
while digit == None:
      digit = kp.getKey()
      fin = digit
      extra = digit
      while fin == extra:
            digit = kp.getKey()
            geb = str(fin) + str(digit)
print geb
```

I need to be able to get a 2 digit number like 12 or 56 but can only get 1 digit numbers right now.

Comment: Assuming your `kp.getKey()` returns a string you can always initialize your digit as `digit = ""`, then use use `while len(digit) < 2` for loop and use `digit += kp.getKey()` within it to collect the digits.

Comment: Do you have a link to the docs for `keypad.getKey`?

Comment: http://crumpspot.blogspot.ca/2013/05/using-3x4-matrix-keypad-with-raspberry.html This is the code i used.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your original code, it looks like `kp.getKey()` will occasionally return `None`. Write your loop to append to a list until it has two elements using the same logic:

```
lst = []
kp = keypad()
while len(list) < 2:
    digit = kp.getKey()
    if digit is not None:
        lst.append(digit)

print ''.join(lst)
```

Comment: this appends the first number twice. if i press 1 I get 11 and no second button press.

Comment: @drako234. That part makes sense if you have to filter the input yourself, but according to the code comments you linked to, the channels get reset after each keypress. Perhaps you need a wait between presses?

Comment: if you were referring to time.sleep() that did not work. is there another way to make it wait? also it seems like getKey() isn't clearing itself out after button presses and i feel that i need to reset rowVal and colVal to -1 after they are returned but i don't think i can do that?

Comment: ok after another test i have discovered that when a button is pressed the getKey() value will stay that way until another key is pressed and the program is reading it constantly. a 5 second sleep did nothing.

Comment: Yeah, sleep won't help in that case. I don't really know much about the hardware end, so I think a better method may be to get in touch with the authors of the blog and ask for their take on it. They look like they know what they're doing.

Answer (score 0):

ok i figured it out:

```
kp = keypad()
list = ['']
digit = None
while True:
      digit = kp.getKey()
      if digit != None and digit != '*':
              list.append(str(digit))
              time.sleep(.5) #otherwise you end up repeating the same number until a new one is pressed 
              digit = None
     elif digit = '*':
              print ''.join(list)
              break
```

this will wait until you hit 1 or more keys and if that key is * then it prints your number and ends the loop.

hopefully this helps out anyone else with this problem.